# Discord Bot on Python: if message contains

Tags: python, discord

Hi there i want to create a discord bot that delete messages that contains bad words. I found only a function *startswith*, but i want to delete message also if it contains bad words.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith("bad_word"):
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args))
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [states](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content) `message.content` is a string, so you are probably looking for:

```py
foo = 'Here is an example string that contains bar.'
if 'bar' in foo:
    print('bar is in foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sort in several bad words you can do like this

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    bad_words = ("bad_word1", "bad_word2", "bad_word3"...)
    if any(bad_word in content for bad_word in bad_words):
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args))
```

I also advise to convert the content to lower case to avoid the possibility of bypassing the system with a capital letter.

```
any(bad_word in content.lower() for bad_word in bad_words)
```